# the inverse of $f(x)=x-x^p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives, inverse

> Provided that $f(x)=x-x^p$, prove that $$f^{-1}(x)=\sum_{k\ge1}{pk\choose k}\frac{x^{1+(p-1)k}}{1+(p-1)k}.$$

I have gotten so far as using the Lagrange Inversion Theorem to show that
$$f^{-1}(x)=\sum_{k\ge1}g_k\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
where 
$$g_k=\lim_{w\to0}\left[\left(\frac{d}{dw}\right)^{k-1}(1-w^{p-1})^{-k}\right],$$
but I have no idea how to compute this limit, or where to go from there. Could I have some help? Thanks :)

Comment: If $g(x)$ is the inverse then $$g'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}=\frac{1}{1-px^{p-1}}$$ Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ahh I see. Thanks. It sort of looks like it might help

Comment: To what set does $p$ belong?

Comment: Doesn't Lagrange need that $f'(0)\neq 0$, for your case?

Comment: @BernardMassé $\Bbb Z_{\ge2}$, I guess

Comment: @clathratus The inverse function cannot exist if p is a positive integer such that $p \ge 2$ since the function is not injective for such values.

Comment: @BernardMassé [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Example) says that the series works for $$|z|\le (p-1)p^{p/(1-p)}$$

Comment: @Sudix that requirement is satisfied for $p>1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, this works only for *integer* $p>1$. You can use (binomial expansion)
$$(1-w^{p-1})^{-k}=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\binom{n+k-1}{n}w^{n(p-1)},$$
see that $g_k\neq 0$ only when $k-1=n(p-1)$ for an integer $\color{red}{n\geqslant 0}$, and get
$$g_{n(p-1)+1}=\binom{np}{n}\big(n(p-1)\big)!$$
as expected. But there is a simplification that also handles *non-integer* $p>1$. The solution $w(z)$ of $w-w^p=z$ we look for is of the form $w(z)=zy(z)$, where $y-z^{p-1}y^p=1$, so that $y$, as a function of $x=z^{p-1}$, satisfies $$x=\frac{y-1}{y^p},$$
and we apply the theorem to this equation (at $y=1$). This gives $y=1+\sum\limits_{k\geqslant 1}g_k x^k$, where
$$g_k=\frac{1}{k!}\lim_{y\to 1}\left(\frac{d}{dy}\right)^{k-1}\color{blue}{y^{pk}}=\frac{1}{k}\binom{pk}{k-1}=\frac{1}{(p-1)k+1}\binom{pk}{k}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have

$$z = q(z) - q(z)^p$$

with $p\ge 2$ an integer and we seek

$$q(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} Q_n z^n.$$

Start with some basic observations namely that

$$[z^0] (q(z)-q(z)^p) = [z^0] z = 0 = Q_0 - Q_0^p.$$

We will choose the branch that has $Q_0 = 0.$
Furthermore we have

$$[z^1] (q(z)-q(z)^p) = [z^1] z = 1 =
[z^1] (Q_1 z + \cdots - Q_1^p z^p - \cdots) = Q_1$$

and hence $Q_1 = 1.$ Using the Cauchy Coefficient Formula
we write

$$n Q_n = [z^{n-1}] q'(z) =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^n} q'(z) \; dz.$$

We put $q(z) = w$ to that $q'(z) \; dz = dw.$ With the chosen branch
we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{(w-w^p)^n} \; dw
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^n} \frac{1}{(1-w^{p-1})^n} \; dw.$$

This yields with the factor in front

$$\frac{1}{n} [w^{n-1}] \frac{1}{(1-w^{p-1})^n}$$

so that we must have $n=(p-1)k+1$ where $k\ge 0.$ We find

$$\frac{1}{(p-1)k+1}
[w^{(p-1)k}] \frac{1}{(1-w^{p-1})^{(p-1)k+1}}
\\= \frac{1}{(p-1)k+1}
[w^{k}] \frac{1}{(1-w)^{(p-1)k+1}}
= \frac{1}{(p-1)k+1} {k+(p-1)k\choose k}.$$

This finally yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
q(z) = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{z^{(p-1)k+1}}{(p-1)k+1}
{pk\choose k}.}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). I must say, however, that I do not know complex analysis. Perhaps I will understand your answer better once I do.